# What is std::ref useful for in this function?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

Why should one prefer to call std::ref instead of not calling it at all?

```
template<class F, class...Ts> F for_each_arg(F f, Ts&&...a) {
  return (void)initializer_list<int>{(ref(f)((Ts&&)a), 0)...}, f;
  // why not return (void)initializer_list<int>{(f((Ts&&)a), 0)...}, f;
}
```

Comment: It's unnecessary. https://twitter.com/ericniebler/status/559798611991879684

Answer (score 17, accepted):

[`std::reference_wrapper::operator()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/reference_wrapper/operator%28%29) performs a bit of "magic" in some cases beyond what a direct function call would. Its effects are specified as (quoting N4296 [refwrap.invoke]):

> ```
> template <class... ArgTypes>
> result_of_t<T&(ArgTypes&&... )>
> operator()(ArgTypes&&... args) const;
> ```
>
> Returns: `INVOKE(get(), std::forward<ArgTypes>(args)...)`. (20.9.2)

where `get()` returns a reference to what the `reference_wrapper` wraps. `INVOKE` is described in 20.9.2 [func.require]:

> Define `INVOKE(f, t1, t2, ..., tN)` as follows:
>
> (1.1) — `(t1.*f)(t2, ..., tN)` when `f` is a pointer to a member function of a class `T` and `t1` is an object of type `T` or a reference to an object of type `T` or a reference to an object of a type derived from `T`;
>
> (1.2) — `((*t1).*f)(t2, ..., tN)` when `f` is a pointer to a member function of a class `T` and `t1` is not one of the types described in the previous item;
>
> (1.3) — `t1.*f` when `N == 1` and `f` is a pointer to member data of a class `T` and `t1` is an object of type `T` or a reference to an object of type `T` or a reference to an object of a type derived from `T`;
>
> (1.4) — `(*t1).*f` when `N == 1` and `f` is a pointer to member data of a class `T` and `t1` is not one of the types described in the previous item;
>
> (1.5) — `f(t1, t2, ..., tN)` in all other cases.

The result of calling `ref(f)` instead of simply `f` is that pointer-to-member-function and pointer-to-member-data can be "called" with an appropriate object pointer/reference as parameter. For example,

```
struct A { void foo(); };
struct B : A {};
struct C : B {};
for_each_arg(&A::foo, A{}, B{}, C{}, std::make_unique<A>());
```

would call `foo` on the `A`, `B` and `C` temporary objects and the object held in the `unique_ptr` ([DEMO](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b87d4cd75e64dd98)). Why one would *prefer* to use `ref(f)` over `f` would obviously depend on the context in which one is using `for_each_arg`.

Comment: Interesting, yet another magic feature of `std::reference_wrapper`. Wondering why Eric Niebler deems it unnecessary then.

Comment: @bamboon Hard to say without more context. I would speculate that `ref()` adds 5 more characters and eliminating it results in shorter code for code golf purposes.

Comment: Why does `auto f = std::ref(&A::foo);` fail, but `auto f = &A::foo; auto f2 = std::ref(f)` succeed?

Comment: @Barry Because `&A::foo` is an rvalue, and `reference_wrapper` has a deleted rvalue constructor to avoid binding to temporary objects. The standard literally says in [refwrap]: `reference_wrapper(T&&) = delete; // do not bind to temporary objects`.

Comment: @Casey Oh right. I was hoping this might end up being a way to do something like `find_if(cont.begin(), cont.end(), std::ref(&T::pred))` but guess not. *Almost*.

Comment: @Barry `[](auto& t){ return t.pred(); }` is a bit longer to type. Hopefully, we'll get [Projection Functions](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4128.html#algorithms-should-take-invokable-projections) in the standard library around C++2x.

Comment: @Barry `std::mem_fn` isn't that much longer.